# remove duplicate SelectListItem? distinct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

good evening
like I had made ​​my listbox bit more orderly
now I dubble names in my listbox

How can I fix that they come according to ABC stand and all dubble took out his

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    ViewBag.country =
        (from t In db.country _
        Select New SelectListItem() With _
        { _
            .Text = t.Name, _
            .Value = t.countryid _
        }).Distinct().ToList()
End Function
@Html.ListBox("country", ViewBag.country)
```

one sample

Before: 1
Before: 5
Before: 2
Before: 3
Before: 6
Before: 4
Before: 4

After: 1
After: 2
After: 3
After: 4
After: 5
After: 6

thex elisa9180

Comment: You should implement `IEqualityComparer` interface, if it was c# I could provide you some code but it's in VB

Comment: A simple Group By would be enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**the solution**

```
  ViewBag.country = (From t In db.country _
                       Select New SelectListItem() With _
                       { _
                           .Text = t.Name, _
                           .Value = t.countryid _
                       }).DistinctBy(Function(c) c.Text)
```

Comment: Apparently, there is distinct and DistinctBy ().

Comment: .DistinctBy is not a standard .net method. You probably have the MoreLinq library.